# WPF Combobox not displaying "Please Select" on load

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Hi I am wondering if someone can point me where I am going wrong in the following code that is preventing the "Please select" item from being the default in the combobox on view load.

```
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ProductCollection" Source="{Binding ProductsCollection}">
  </CollectionViewSource>


  <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0"
        Width="120"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
     <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
           <ComboBoxItem Content="Please Select" />
           <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductCollection}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
     </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
  </ComboBox>
```

----- Updated code -----

Thank you Sajeetharan, however, the Please Select text does not even appear now. But the collection items do, anything wrong with the change?

```
  <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="139,336,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        SelectedIndex="0"
        Width="120"
        Text="Please Select"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsCollection}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change from ComboBox  Content to Text,

```
<ComboBox  IsEditable="True"  Text="Please Select" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductCollection}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan, can you look at my updated code above and see what could be wrong? I think I have followed your code OK!

Comment: Add these 2 properties to your combobox then it will be alright IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"

Comment: @user3428422 You need to add IsEditable="True".It will display the Text property of the Combobox

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work when I put in DisplayMemberPath porperty, as I am binding from a observable collection, I need to show a property of that collection, I guess this method wont work now?

Comment: @user3428422 then you need to add the please select as a string to your observable collection and display it

Comment: Yeah I thought so, didn't want to do that, but it is the quickest way I guess!

Comment: @user3428422 yes this is the quickest way